# Troubleshooting Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-core, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 for authentication. I have MVC client. Few days ago i was able to authenticate successfully. But recently i made some changes in Identity Server project which broke something. I am getting

> unauthorized_client The client application is not known or is not authorized.

I tried all the possible fixes but couldn't fix it. Is there any way i can debug the code. I could see that the call was made to `/connect/authorize` endpoint and calls are going to `IScopeStore.FindScopesAsync` and `IClientStore.FindClientByIdAsync` and i verified it has all proper `AllowedScopes`.

Can anyone tell me how do i troubleshoot these kind of issues with Identity Server 4. Also, i am interested to know the execution flow. What IDSvr endpoints are called and when?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your problem can be anything. enable logging to the console and you can find out what it is. Identity Server 4 by default uses the asp.net core logger provider to do its internal logging.

in your `Startup.cs` within the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)` method. Add Console logging by `loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Trace);` and make sure that you include the logger extension package in your project.json `"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",`.

Comment: Thanks Lutando.  I am not getting any exception. ID Server is giving me that error message and i am not sure why it's throwing error. I am just wondering how do i debug my code when ID server endpoint gets called. e.g  `/connect/authorize.`

Comment: It might not be an exception. IdentityServer4's logging is quite descriptive. When you make the request to the authorization endpoint what does the logger say? maybe you can paste it here so I can see.

Comment: I have enabled logging into console but cannot see any logs. I get exceptions only on DeveloperExceptionPage. Can you tell me where to look for errors on console.

Comment: If you logging on Console it should just appear in the console. setting the minimum LogLevel to trace will basically also show all trace info.

Heres an example of how my logs log in console:

```
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: 
      Processing token request.

--- omitted for brevity ---
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.Default.DefaultClaimsProvider[0]
      Getting claims for access token for client: identityapipostman_identityapi
trce: IdentityServer4.Services.Default.DefaultTokenService[0]
      Creating JWT access token

```

Comment: I am not using selfhost. I am using a asp.net MVC web project.

Comment: are you hosting using asp.net MVC Core?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123853/discussion-between-lutando-and-venky).

Comment: We are using the standard ASP.NET Core logging - enable that for trace/debug level.

Answer (score 0):

Your client_id and (Client config) sent in the /connect/authorize request must match exactly ClientId configured on IdentityServer4. To debug, use the output window to read the log messages or log the a file.